# How to get ASP.NET Core Windows Service to look for files in certain directory?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core minimal API which I want to run as Windows Service.
It uses a couple of files. The paths to these files are provided by the appsettings.json, and are relative to directory of the exe.

When running it as a Windows Service, it discovers the appsettings.json, which is also located in the same directory as the exe, just fine and reads the values. However, reading other files does not work: it starts looking at C:\Windows\System32. I understand that this is normal behavior for Windows Services, so I have provided a ContentRootPath as mentioned here: [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service). But that seems to not affect it:

```
var options = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    Args = args,
    ContentRootPath = WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService() 
        ? AppContext.BaseDirectory : default
};
 
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

...
builder.Host.UseWindowsService();
var app = builder.Build();
...
app.Run();
```

It still tries to read from System32, and also writes the log files here.
The only fix I have been able to find was using the following:

```
if (WindowsServiceHelpers.IsWindowsService())
{
    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
}
```

Is there a 'correct' way to tell an ASP.NET Core application running as Windows Service to use a certain directory as its content root?

Answer (score 0):

Your method should work, the role of `Directory.setCurrenTDirectory (String)` method is to set the current working directory of the application to the specified directory.

[`AppDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=net-7.0) Properties Get the Basic Directory Path, you can try to change it to your own directory:

```
// Create string for a directory. This value should be an existing directory
string dir = @"C:\test";
//Set the current directory.
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir);
//GetCurrentDirectory obtains the current working directory
Console.WriteLine("Current directory: {0}", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
```

For more details, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0).